# Dynamic homepage according to user role

Tags: plugins, user-roles, homepage

I have develop a wordpress website consulting and I have different user role

and I want to have different content according to user role

so I have a landing page with authentification and according the user role login , the homepage is different

so I would like to say if plugin who make something like this exist or if can code for that

so recap :

Home page for not login is landing page 
home page for user login is different according to user role

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a different page's content on the homepage based on a logged-in user's role you can do this:

In your functions.php file add this code:

```
function wpse_273872_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
  if ( $query->is_main_query() && is_user_logged_in() ) {
    //work-around for using is_front_page() in pre_get_posts
    //known bug in WP tracked by https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21790
    $front_page_id = get_option('page_on_front');
    $current_page_id = $query->get('page_id');
    $is_static_front_page = 'page' == get_option('show_on_front');

    if ($is_static_front_page && $front_page_id == $current_page_id) {
      $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
      $user = new WP_User($current_user->ID);
      if (in_array('cs_candidate', $user->roles)) { //assuming the role name is cs_candidate
        $query->set('page_id', [page-id-for-candidate-homepage]);
      } elseif (in_array('cs_employer', $user->roles)) { //assuming the role name is cs_employer
        $query->set('page_id', [page-id-for-employer-homepage]);
      }
    }
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_273872_pre_get_posts' );
```

What this does is:

1. Filters the wp_query args if a user is logged in, you're on the homepage and it's the main query
2. If the user has the role 'candidate', set the post id (p) to the ID of the page you created and change the post_type to 'page'
3. Similarily, if the user has a role employer, use the ID for that page.

Thanks for helping clarify all your points.

Comment: finale it dosnt work ...

Comment: the homepage not change

Comment: Can you elaborate? I'd like to help, but you need to give more information on what isn't working since you had previously reported that this solution was working. What is not working about it??

Comment: in add the function like before and I thinking the homepage change but no I
the homepage is not change 
i have delete [ ] because I see in the different discussion they dont have [ ] for id 
but I don't why Is not working 
I try to check if the role existing and yes is same to function 
maybe is my function is not put in good place ?

if you want to chat directly you can join chat here : https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62457/discussion-between-ouanounou-and-danbrellis

Comment: yes, that' right, the square brackets were just to indicate placeholders. It should be `$query->set('p', 423);` if 423 is the ID of the page

Comment: i have try to get role with var dump but I have nothing in the console

Comment: I have updated the answer. The most important things was that since you want to show a Page's content, the code needed to set the page_id query_var: `$query->set('page_id', ...)`. There is also some different logic for determining the front_page (more info as a comment in the code). In addition, I did improve the other function in your functions.php that was hooking into pre_get_posts. I commented out the bad lines of code so you can see the changes I made.

Answer (score 1):

Two options come to mind. Which one will depend on how different your content is for logged in/not logged in.

1) The first, you can just use IF statements on the homepage template.

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$user = new WP_User( $current_user ->ID);

if($user && in_array('my-role', $user->roles)){
    //stuff specific to users with 'my-role'
}
.
.
.
else{
    //stuff for non logged in users or ones that don't match any of your roles
}
```

2) The second option is to filter the template based on their role. You can hook into the `template_include` filter. See the examples in the codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include. With this option you could have multiple templates for various users and use a different one dynamically if you keep consistent with a template naming convention.

Hopefully this helps. Depending on which option you take I can help provide some more detailed code examples.

**UPDATED**

Based on the information in your comments, here is an example using the `template_include` filter hook. You can put this in your functions.php. Untested code:

```
function wpse_273872_template_include($template) {
  //if user is not logged in, just return and show the default homepage
  if(!is_user_logged_in()) return $template;

  $new_template = '';
  $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
  $user = new WP_User( $current_user->ID);

  if(in_array('candidate', $user->roles)){ //assuming the role name is candidate
    $new_template = locate_template( array( 'homepage-candidate.php' ) );
  }
  elseif(in_array('company', $user->roles)){ //assuming the role name is company
    $new_template = locate_template( array( 'homepage-company.php' ) );
  }
  if ( '' != $new_template ) {
    $template = $new_template;
  }
  return $template;
}
add_filter( 'template_include', 'wpse_273872_template_include' );
```

The homepage-candidate.php and homepage-company.php are template files that reside in your theme's folder. Here is an example of the file structure:

```
- my-custom-theme
    |- style.css
    |- functions.php
    |- frontpage.php
    |- homepage-candidate.php
    |- homepage-company.php
```

Comment: if you need to access to my website www.myk-consulting.com

Comment: thanks to reply me , i this the second option is more adapt for my situation 
I need 3 template if user is not login, if candidate is login and if user company is login 
so how can be do that I not really understanding the doc 

and I want to the url of my home page stay www.myk-consulting.com

and is not 3 url different 

is it possible ?


thanks

Comment: Yes, it's possible. I misspoke about the hook you should. You'll actually want the `template_include` filter. I'm putting together a more comprehensive answer- stand by.

Comment: but I dont have homepage-company.php and homepage-candidate.php  I have juste 3 different page but I want the url is same

Comment: what do you mean, "3 different page"? The homepage-company.php and homepage-candidate.php are just files in your theme's folder that are the template files. They can be named whatever you want and those files will be displayed instead of home.php (or frontpage.php or index.php).

Comment: i have create 2 home pages but now they have a different url for this pages  and how can be access to the php class of this pages if it possible ?

Comment: I don't have this file in my theme

Answer (score 0):

i have create my page directly in wordpress like this 
[image]

so I have now just one home page in my file template call  index.php

and my 2 page is not in this file

Comment: By the way, you should edit your original question to add more details, not post an answer.

Comment: Okay, now I see what you mean. I thought you were editting your theme's files. A new answer coming up.

Comment: actually, before I answer, are you able to edit/add any new files in your theme? What theme are you using? Is it a custom theme, child theme, etc?

Comment: yes I can add file in my theme I  use job career template 
I buy this template and I have custom some things 
is not a child template I dont have activate now because I have some bug with him but is not really hard to fix that 

i have create all my page directly in wordpress without create file php directly in my template file

Comment: if you need admin access or ftp access I can give you if you want

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62457/discussion-between-ouanounou-and-danbrellis).

Answer (score 0):

I use Gravity Forms and with the User Registration, I have a custom field, "UserType2".
Depending on the UserType2 variable in the MySQL UserMeta Table I give different access to Fields on my Gravity Form linked to my Homepage with Conditional Logic.
Then I can have as many as I want.

This way I don't need to change anything on the PHP files.