# dynamic home page according to role user

Tags: user-roles, homepage

i want to have different homepage according the user role login

if the user is not log they have a landing page with login

if a candidate is log the home page is custom for candidate

if a employer is log the home page is custom for employer

i have create my home page directly in wordpress not in code with page.php

and I want to have the same url for 3 home page

so I write in other question here : [Dynamic homepage according to user role](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/273870/dynamic-homepage-according-to-user-role)

I try that :

```
   function wpse_273872_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
  if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    if(!is_user_logged_in()) return;

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user = new WP_User( $current_user->ID);

    if(in_array('candidate', $user->roles)){ //assuming the role name is candidate
      $query->set('p', [ID of the page you created for candidate]);
      $query->set('post_type', 'page');
    }
    elseif(in_array('company', $user->roles)){ //assuming the role name is company
      $query->set('p', [ID of the page you created for employer]);
      $query->set('post_type', 'page');
    }
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_273872_pre_get_posts' );
```

but he doesn't work I dont now why

any solution ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

`$query->is_home()` is not, well, 'home'. `$query->is_home()` checks of you are viewing the blog/posts page. It's an artifact from when the home page of WordPress sites was invariably the blog. You want to change that to `$query->is_front_page()`, which checks if the front page of the website is a page, and if you are on that page.

Comment: ok and it's already in function.php ?

Comment: I don't understand the question. The code can be in functions.php or a plugin. All you need to is change the bit I mentioned, and replace the "`[ID of the page you created for employer]`" bits with the action ID.

Comment: this function who have code I put in function.php

Comment: but I try and now my website is down blank page

Comment: You've left in the placeholder `[ID of the page you created for employer]` from the previous answer. You need to replace that with the actual ID.

Comment: yes like that :

Comment: maybe is where I put this function in my function.php who down. my website ?

Comment: my website is on now but is already same the homepage doesn't change if I connect in candidat for example

Comment: do you have any idea ?

Comment: `[7764]` should be `7764`. The other one too.

The code will work then, but only if the candidate and company roles exist and 7764 and 8655 are the correct ids.

Comment: doesn't work ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62515/discussion-between-ouanounou-and-jacob-peattie).